# Creating Oracle Cursor using Java Program

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wanted to create Oracle Cursor with the help of Java Code. I tried searching on the Internet but I didn't find anything. Can we create Cursor using Java code?

Comment: Through which platform ? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: We are trying to optimize the performance of our application. Sorry, I did not get the first question, by platform do you mean the Operating System?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43710288/1509264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a cursor using Java code.

A cursor is a reference (pointer) to a data structure internal to the database representing a query and a corresponding set of results - creating the pointer outside of the database would be meaningless.

From the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/procedures_plsql.htm#TDPNG60035):

> ## Introduction to `REF CURSOR`s
>
> Using `REF CURSOR`s is one of the most powerful, flexible, and scalable ways to return query results from an Oracle Database to a client application.
>
> `REF CURSOR` is a PL/SQL data type whose value is the memory address of a query work area on the database. In essence, a `REF CURSOR` is a pointer or a handle to a result set on the database. `REF CURSOR`s are represented through the `OracleRefCursor` ODP.NET class.
>
> `REF CURSOR`s have the following characteristics:
>
> - A `REF CURSOR` refers to a memory address on the database. Therefore, the client must be connected to the database during the lifetime of the `REF CURSOR` in order to access it.
> - A `REF CURSOR` involves an additional database round-trip. While the `REF CURSOR` is returned to the client, the actual data is not returned until the client opens the `REF CURSOR` and requests the data. Note that data is not be retrieved until the user attempts to read it.
> - A `REF CURSOR` is not updatable. The result set represented by the `REF CURSOR` is read-only. You cannot update the database by using a `REF CURSOR`.
> - A `REF CURSOR` is not backward scrollable. The data represented by the `REF CURSOR` is accessed in a forward-only, serial manner. You cannot position a record pointer inside the `REF CURSOR` to point to random records in the result set.
> - A `REF CURSOR` is a PL/SQL data type. You create and return a `REF CURSOR` inside a PL/SQL code block.

You need to create a stored procedure (or function) in the database that returns a cursor and then invoke that from your external application.